# Query string query from javascript client

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am using elasticsearch 5.5 and my query is

```
client.search({
  index: 'sample',
  type: 'data',
  body: {
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "state:req.params.state AND city:req.params.city AND postalcode:req.params.pc"
      }
    }
  }
}
})
```

In this code `req.params.state`, `req.params.city` and `req.params.pc` are user given values which are considered as value(string) itself and returns nothing because double quotes are used.

So when I tried to remove double quotes the AND operater used is not validated as operator and throws an error.

Comment: Looks like you already got the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to build the query differently, in a dynamic way, like this.

```
const input = {
  'state': 'state',
  'city': 'city',
  'pc': 'postcode'
};
const query = [];
Object.keys(input).forEach(p => {
   if (req.params[p]) {
      query.push([input[p], req.params[p]].join(":"));
   }
});

client.search({
  index: 'sample',
  type: 'data',
  body:{
    "query":{
      "query_string": {
        "query": query.length ? query.join(" AND ") : "*"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.The query worked well. I'm having one more doubt How can I place asterisk(*) in my query if my parameter (req.params.city) is searched with empty

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not getting any response.How can I handle this empty field request.If the field is empty it should get me all  city value with combination of AND operation with other fields.So I thought of using asterisk(*) to get all values of my city.Any tips to solve this?

Comment: I've taken another approach and now build the query in a dynamic way depending on which parameters are present in the input

Comment: Thanks you are helping lot but this dynamic code works when all the fields are given.If any field is not searched it is not getting the results back.What can I do to make this work?

Comment: I've updated again my answer. If no field is searched, then we just search for `"*"` and that would yield all documents.

Comment: Again it end up in the same issue :(

Comment: Can you show the query that gets generated? Just print it out using `console.log()`

Comment: This is the error its showing - "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".I have searched for city and state as Baltimore and MD and left the field Postalcode. The request becomes http://localhost:3000/search-title/Baltimore/MD/  and not like http://localhost:3000/search-title/Baltimore/MD/*.Query doesn't replace empty field search with asterisk(*).

Comment: I want to see the query your code is sending to ES not the one from the browser to your node backend

Comment: That error makes me think that the problem is not on ES side, but the request cannot be handled by your node server because of that `*` character. Maybe you need to URL-encode the parameters before sending the request. `Failed to load resource` is not ES-related, but more on the node.js side

Comment: Yeah I will check with node.js code.Thank you so much for all your suggestions and works.Thanks a lot :)